# Objective-C (iPhone dev)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, setter, getter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explain to me what is a setter and getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649096/explain-to-me-what-is-a-setter-and-getter)

What are setters and getters? couldn't find it on wikipedia and in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method

Comment: didn't explain this very good...

Answer (score 0):

They are ofter referred to as `mutators` and `accessors`.

A search for `mutator`/`accessor` yielded following result:

> In computer science, a mutator method is a method used to control changes to a variable.
>   The mutator method, sometimes called a "setter", is most often used in object-oriented programming, in keeping with the principle of encapsulation. According to this principle, member variables of a class are made private to hide and protect them from other code, and can only be modified by a public member function (the mutator method), which takes the desired new value as a parameter, optionally validates it, and modifies the private member variable.
>   Often a "setter" is accompanied by a "getter" (also known as an accessor), which returns the value of the private member variable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method

---

You can use this paradigm in in Onbjectice-C via [declared properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html):

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *value;
}
@property(copy, readwrite) NSString *value;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize value;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Getters and Setters are methods on an object that allow you to hide the internal implementation of something but still allow other objects to access things. They also allow you to do validation or other tasks when they are called.

In objective-c, they are tied to the idea of properties - if you define a property you get getters and setters for the object's function.

For example, what if you wanted to know how many times something has been asked for?

```
@interface MyDataHolder {
    NSData *data;
    NSInteger count;
}

@property (readonly) NSData *data;

@end
```

and in your .m file

```
@implementation MyDataHolder
...
- (NSData *)data {
   count ++;
   return data;
}
```

Now, just by asking for the data, count is incremented as well.

There's more documentation [about properties here](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-properties-setters-and-dot-syntax.html) and @jussi's link is a better overview of getters/setters in general.