# Should we add attr_* methods in Ruby when creating a Class?

Tags: ruby

I create class in Ruby without any attr_* method like attr_reader, or attr_writer or attr_accessor.
So something like this

```
class DocumentIdentifier
 def initialize( folder, name )
  @folder = folder
  @name = name
 end
end
```

I mean it can be instantiated like this right

```
di = DocumentIdentifier.new(folder, 'image')
```

But i read some codes in some ruby books they also add attr_* to the instance variable like this

```
class DocumentIdentifier
 attr_reader :folder, :name
 def initialize( folder, name )
  @folder = folder
  @name = name
 end
end
```

My question is, should we use attr_* in every class definition and why is the reason?

Comment: This is a general OOP question: When we have a class with some instance variables - under what condition should we provide getter and setter methods? This is not specific to Ruby, and this question has been discussed for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649096/explain-to-me-what-is-a-setter-and-getter) or [here](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices#Why).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain to me what is a setter and getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649096/explain-to-me-what-is-a-setter-and-getter)

Comment: yeah maybe it is general oop question but i also wanna if there is some ruby thingy answer, but it is a general oop question, so yeah you are right @user1934428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_reader` will create methods that will return your instance variables with matching names.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

This means that instances of `Foo` will both internally and externally have the method `bar`, that will respond with the value of the instance variable `@bar`:

```
foo = Foo.new(1)
foo.bar
=> 1
```

It's better to depend on behavior (a method) than on data (direct instance variable).

If you access the data through the methods generated by `attr_reader` you're ensuring you'll make your code slightly more "future proof" by encapsulating behavior in the same place, so **it's always best to access all your instance variables through them**.

Another interesting aspect is that you can limit your interface to match your needs. There's no need to expose `bar` to the outside world if you only use internally for instance, so:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

  def zoo
    bar
  end


  private

  attr_reader :bar
end
```

Will behave like:

```
foo = Foo.new(1)
foo.zoo
=> 1
```

But:

```
foo.bar
NoMethodError (private method `bar' called for #<Foo:0x00005581544b83d8 @bar=1>)
```

Please let me know if that makes sense, otherwise I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: i do get what you explain, so based your answer, i think it based on what we will gonna do to the class or the object, if we want to expose the instance variable so we can use attr_reader or any attr_*. if we do not want it so just dont use the attr_* or make it private

Comment: My point was even if you don't want to expose it externally, do use it still, only make it private, so even internally your class has a common interface to access the variable. If you found that acceptable, could you please accept the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader` is a "getter method". In other words, it allows us to declare that a data attribute will be publicly read-able.

When you save a data attribute on an instance of a class, that data can't be viewed from outside of the class by default. With `attr_reader` set, we can access that attribute from anywhere.

Here's an example using the "name" field from your question.

```
# without "attr_reader"
class DocumentIdentifier
   def initialize(folder, name)
      @folder = folder
      @name = name
  end
end

first_example = DocumentIdentifier.new(nil, 'test')

first_example.name
```

This will give an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/ibell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/ibell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/ibell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):9
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for #<DocumentIdentifier:0x00007fe0160956e8 @folder=2, @name="l">)
```

Now, if you add the `attr_accessor`, the same code will work.

```
class DocumentIdentifier
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(folder, name)
    @folder = folder
    @name = name
  end
end

second_example = DocumentIdentifier.new(nil, 'test')

second_example.name
```

This will give you the string "test" back.

Just as we need to read data, we might also want to write it. `attr_writer` works similarly to `attr_reader`, but it allows us to "set" data.

```
class DocumentIdentifier
  attr_writer :name
  def initialize(folder, name)
    @folder = folder
    @name = name
  end
end

second_example = DocumentIdentifier.new(nil, 'test')

second_example.name = 'we can change this text'

second_example.name
```

This will give you back: `'we can change this text'`

Lastly, `attr_accessor` is a shortcut for when you want `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` on the same attribute.